# JavaScript RegEx to match url path

Tags: javascript, regex

I have possible url paths as below

```
/articles
/payment
/about
/articles?page=1
/articles/hello-world
```

I would like to match only the main path of the url, expected matches: `['articles', 'payment', 'about', 'articles', 'articles']`

So I tried to construct the JavaScript [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/quuH30/1) and came up with as nearest as I can `[a-z].*(?=\/|\?)`, unfortunately it only matches string inside the last two

Please guide
Thanks everyone

Comment: Why are _these_ paths valid? Would there be other paths that would be valid? Can't you do it via whitelisting and strings?

Comment: I intend to use `window.location.pathname` then extract only the main path from the fullpath

Comment: Those paths are all possibilities of my site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/A86hYz/1

```
/^\/([^?\/]+)/
```

This regex captures everything between the first / and either the second / or the first ? if they exist. This seems like the pattern you want. If it isn't, let me know and I'll adjust it as needed. Some simple adjustments would be capturing what's between every / as well as capturing the query parameters.

For future reference, when writing regex, try to avoid the lookahead/behind unless you have to as they usually introduce bugs. It's easiest if you stick to using the regular operators.

To access the match, use the regex like this:

```
var someString = '/articles?page=1';
var extracted = someString.match(/^\/([^?\/]+)/)[1]
```

or more generally

```
function getMainPath(str) {
    const regex = /^\/([^?\/]+)/;
    return str.match(regex)[1];
}
```

Comment: That's exactly how I want, also thanks for warning not to use lookahead/behind :)